# ELMO 2012 Shortlist N9

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elliptic-curves

I'll admit that I've made no progress to solve this one. It is way too hard. I guess I must do some stuffs with elliptic curve to solve it but I got nowhere

So, here is the problem:

Are there positive integers $m,n$ such that there exist at least $2012$ positive integers $x$ such that both $m-x^2$ and $n-x^2$ are perfect squares?

*Proposed by David Yang*

Original thread: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95120/number-of-x-such-that-m-x2-and-n-x2-are-both-squares

AoPS thread: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h486950p2731268

Comment: According to the MO link, the answer is yes.  So what are you asking us?

Comment: I'm asking for rigorous proof for that conclusion